# Aligning a DIV within a table cell

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table with three columns. In the right most column, I want to right-align the content. In an attempt to do this, I have the following:

```
<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='width:100%;'>
  <tr>
    <td>Content 1</td>
    <td>Content 2</td>
    <td style='text-align-right'>Content 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The content in the third cell is actually generated via some server-side code. When the generate content is text, the content is aligned properly. However, when I attempt to right-align a DIV element that is within the third cell, it does not do it. The DIV is always left-aligned. How do I right-align a DIV within a table cell?

Thank you!

Comment: FYI, there's a typo in the last td, it's "text-align: right". Might be the problem..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your code should look like this to meet both div and non-div situations:

```
<td style="text-align:right;">
  <div style="float: right;" align="right"></div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 5):

Put a class to the td

```
<td class="rightAlign">
```

and define a css class with the text-align property with !important

```
.rightAlign{
    text-align: right !important
}
```

this will make the DIV inherit the right alignment.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
<td><div style="float: right;"></div></td>
```